# Deploying ODP.NET website

Tags: asp.net, web-deployment, odp.net, odt

I am trying to deploy ASP.NET 4.0 based website using "ODAC 12.1.0.1.0 with Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio". Ive configured the website on IIS and installed "ODAC 12.1.0.1.0 with Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio"

The problem is that the connection isnt opening, exception is thrown and caught, but there is no exception message in ex.message.

There is no connectivity issue, the Oracle Sql developer does connect to the oracle server
and retrieves data.

64-bit environment and 64-bit ODAC.

Please help.

Comment: Were you able to figure out this? If so pls. share the solution

Comment: yes, i used the previous version of ODAC...i think it was 11.something...

Comment: Did you install the Instant Client at Deployment Server?